# Setting environment variables in the current environment with python (win32com)

Tags: python, windows, winapi, pywin32

I'm trying to use python to set environment variables that will persist in Pythons **parent environment**, even after python exits back to the shell, but **will not persist** once the parent shell is closed.  Opening a new shell should require that the python script be run again in order to set the environment correctly.

Based off the recommendations from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/488449/can-a-python-script-persistently-change-a-windows-environment-variable-elegantl/488696#488696) post, I'm trying to do this using the win32com python library.  Unfortunately, I have very little experience with the win32 api.

Basically, I need a way to get a handle to the current environment, and set environment variables in such a way that they will persist in python's parent environment, but will not persist after the parent environment exits.

Comment: You seem **a little excitable**.  (And to people flagging comments for being jokes: you've proven that community-based moderation does not work.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to change the environment of the parent, by design. The best you can do is have your program emit commands that alter the environment, and then the caller of your program needs to eval the output of your command.

Answer (score 1):

The linked post tells how to change the *default* environment which will affect new processes. It manipulates registry values.

[*"A process can never directly change the environment variables of another process that is not a child of that process"*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682009%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), says MS documentation. So you'll never reach your stated goal from within a child process, Python or not.