# Running scripts whose purpose is to change shell variables with subprocess.popen

Tags: python, windows, popen

I have a series of scripts I am automating the calling of in python with `subprocess.Popen`.  Basically, I call script A, then script B, then script C and so forth.

Script A sets a bunch of local shell variables, with commands such as `set SOME_VARIABLE=SCRIPT_A`, `set PATH=%SCRIPT_A:/=\;%PATH%`.

Script B and C then need to have the effects of this.  In unix, you would call script A with "`source script_a.sh`".  The effect lasts in the current command window.  However, subprocess.Popen effectively launches a new window (kind of).

Apparently `subprocess.Popen` is not the command I want to do this.  How would I do it?

**edit** I have tried parsing the file (which is all 'set' statements) and passing them as a dictionary to 'env' in subprocess.Popen, but it doesn't seem to have all worked..

Comment: Similar: [How do I make environment variable changes stick in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/488366/), [Can a python script persistently change a Windows environment variable? (elegantly)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/488449/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`env`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) argument to Popen with a python dictionary containing the variables then you don't need to run the command that just sets variables.

Comment: But this file changes every so often, and I don't want to update my python script with this every time.  Wouldn't I have to do that?

Comment: Either that or you write an interpreter in Python for the minimal shell command subset that would allow you to set your variables.

Comment: No fun... Is there an alternative to subprocess.Popen that preserves the current command window?

Answer (score 0):

if 'script A' get generated by another process, you will either need to change the other process so the output file is in a format that you can source (`import`) into your python script. or write a parser in python that can digest the vars out of 'Script A' setting them within your python script.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to call a series of batch files using Python you could create a helper batch file which would call all these batch files like this

```
call scriptA;
call scriptB;
call scriptC;
```

and run this helper batch file using `subprocess.Popen`